# Allow paging for dynamic gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a wizard control that has dynamically created steps. Each step contains a gridview control that is also dynamically created.

The page allows users to upload multiple excel files which are then displayed in a wizard control. More specifically, the files are displayed in gridviews which are dynamically created in steps of the wizard control.

How do I enable paging of each gridview programmatically? The markup is shown below:

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Frontend.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="FileUpload_Multi.aspx.cs" Inherits="Analysis_Files_FileUpload_Multi" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cpMainContent" Runat="Server">
   <span style="font-family: Arial">Supported file formats: .csv, .xls, .xlsx<br />
    <br />
    Click to add files</span>
   <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" Text="Add" OnClick="OnAdd" runat="server" />
   <asp:Panel ID="pnlTemp" runat="server">
   </asp:Panel>
   <br />
   <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
    <asp:Label ID="lbl_upload" runat="server" Text="No file added!" 
        Visible="False"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="lbl_fileformat" runat="server" Text="File format not supported!" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Panel id="wizardPanel" runat="server" >
    </asp:Panel>
    <br />
</asp:Content>
```

The code behind is shown below:

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Files.Count == 0)
    {
        this.pnlTemp.Controls.Clear();
        lbl_upload.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        this.pnlTemp.Controls.Clear();
        Wizard gvWizard = new Wizard();

        for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpPostedFile PostedFile = Request.Files[i];
            if (PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string ConStr = "";
                string ext = Path.GetExtension(PostedFile.FileName).ToLower();

                string FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(PostedFile.FileName);
                string path = Server.MapPath("~/Analysis/Files/" + FileName);
                PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Files\\") + FileName); //save file to drive for future use
                WizardStepBase newStep = new WizardStep();
                newStep.ID = "uploadFile" + (i + 1);
                newStep.Title = FileName;

                if (ext.Trim() == ".xls")
                {
                    //connection string for that file which extantion is .xls  
                    ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                }
                else if (ext.Trim() == ".xlsx")
                {
                    //connection string for that file which extantion is .xlsx  
                    ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                }  
                else if (ext.Trim() == ".csv") //not working yet!
                {
                    ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;FMT=CSVDelimited'";
                }
                else
                {
                    lbl_fileformat.Visible = true;
                    break;
                }


                GridView gridview = new GridView();
                gridview.ID = "gd" + (i + 1);


                //bind gridview
                string query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";
                //Providing connection  
                OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConStr);
                //checking that connection state is closed or not if closed the   
                //open the connection  
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    conn.Open();
                }
                //create command object  
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
                // create a data adapter and get the data into dataadapter  
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                //fill the Excel data to data set  
                da.Fill(ds);
                //set data source of the grid view  
                gridview.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                //binding the gridview  
                gridview.DataBind();
                //close the connection  
                conn.Close();

                newStep.Controls.Add(gridview);

                gvWizard.WizardSteps.Add(newStep);
            }
            else
            {
                this.pnlTemp.Controls.Clear();
                lbl_upload.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        wizardPanel.Controls.Add(gvWizard);
        gvWizard.FinishCompleteButtonText = "Analyze data";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can grammatically set Paging like this.

```
GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
GridView1.PageSize = 50;
GridView1.PageIndexChanged += GridView1_PageIndexChanged;

GridView1.DataBind();
```

You have to keep in mind however that since you are binding these to a dynamically created control, and changing a page causes a PostBack, that the GrdView Control has to be recreated on every PostBack.